# Edit tabs and configure gears are missing on all content types in my drupal 7 website

Tags: blocks

How can I get my edit tabs and configure gears to appear? I switched themes and they appeared, but they just seem to not be working in the theme that I am now using.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://drupal.org/update/themes/6/7#title-prefix-suffix ...does your theme's node.tpl.php have `<?php print $title_prefix; ?>` in it? If not, that's the problem

Comment: The file has that in it for each time the title is displayed.

Comment: It also has the print $title_suffix after the title is displayed.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it's just a theme change which prompts the issue? Maybe you're also logged in as a different user who doesn't have the allow contextual filters permission?

Comment: Are you saying that, when switching a theme, the contextual filters permissions can change?

Comment: Not when you change theme, no, I was asking if you're also changing users?

Comment: No, I am not changing users.

Comment: (I had node.tpl.php before I corrected this message) My page.tpl.php doesn't have the print title_prefix.  Does this matter?

Comment: See the first comment...yes, it matters considerably :)

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong file in the comment above. I meant the page.tpl.php

Comment: Doh, forgot about that one. Yep, page.tpl.php needs it too. Add `<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>` before the main `<h1>` (and the suffix after if you need to) and you should be good to go

Comment: You can put the answer below, and I will check it. If not I'll answer the question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page.tpl.php needs $title_prefix too. Add  before the main  (and the suffix after if you need to)